# Google Cardboard Camera Automatically Rotates

Tags: android, rotation, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I created 3D Video App using Google Cardboard for Unity. This is for Android.

However, a problem has occurred. This app's camera is rotated alone. But other devices don't rotate automatically. This problem occurs mainly to Galaxy Note (My Phone Galaxy S5 doesn't rotate).

Maybe Cardboard used the Gyroscope. So, is this caused by the device or the Gyroscope? Why does the Camera rotate automatically? Any help is appreciated.

Here are my component settings:

[image: Component1]

[image: Component2]

Comment: I met this problem too on note4, and when i switch to another phone, it did not happen. And i advice you to open an issue on github, or find the issue i opened.

Comment: Some Android phone sensors are really bad, we experienced this in several app we developed, there´s nothing practical (time wise) to do against it, it´s the manufacturers implementation of the sensors.

Answer (score 1):

[Gyro's drift](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061227205751AA8V3ZL). Normally you perform some kind of [Sensor Fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion) to mitigate this, usually with accelerometer data. On Android, this is already done for you. I think it's recommended to use [sensorManager.getOrientation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float[],%20float[]%29). This should provide a fusion of the various sensors on the device for better accuracy.